# Select a bunch of records with known random ids

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the best way to select a fairly large amount (20-50) rows with random IDs given from array?

For example such code would work (I guess)

```
$array = [1, 53, 11, 334, 5, 96, ...]; // about 50 elements but could be more;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (' . substr(str_repeat('?,', count($array)), -1) . ')';

$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute($array);

$st->fetchAll(); // results
```

I remember I have read answers in the past suggesting to avoid `IN` because it is slow.

What is the best possible technique to perform this operation?

Comment: it's not "slow", but for large `in` sets, there's better ways of doing it, e.g. create a temp table with the `in` values inside it, then `join` against that table.

Comment: tried the above? is it to slow for your purposes?

Comment: It's slow without indexes, but if that's your primary key column it's totally fine to do that. This is by the book how to do it.

Comment: @Dagon it may do the job but I'm talking theoretically. Education is key, no?

Comment: S.O is about practical  questions, not theory "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Comment: @Dagon oops, where should I post this?

Comment: I guess what @MarcB suggested would be the answer to this question, though.

Comment: @tadman interesting point, but it doesn't seem OK to have a query with 100 question marks, or is it just me?

Comment: So long as you don't overflow the [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html) setting, which is adjustable and defaults to around 1MB, you can have as many as you want, it doesn't matter. If you're going to end up with an absurd number of these, maybe you need to express this query as a `JOIN`. In practice, `IN` works very well on indexed data.

Comment: `maybe you need to express this query as a JOIN` That's basically what I want to find out how to do. I only found this http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/ but it's unclear how I can do this without a procedure.